# How to implement SDE DPM Solver

Tags: pytorch, stable-diffusion

I checked out the paper of SDE DPM Solver and I'm trying to implement it in my code but I'm unable to do so. I'm only getting a black image as an output whereas the DDPM sampler is working fine.

For details, this code is working as I followed a YouTube tutorial of creating a stable diffusion model from scratch using pytorch. Here is my code. `self.t = 1`

```
    def _get_previous_timestep(self, timestep: int) -> int:
        prev_t = timestep - self.num_train_timesteps // self.num_inference_steps
        return prev_t
    
    def _get_next_timestep(self, timestep: int) -> int:
        next_t = timestep + self.num_train_timesteps // self.num_inference_steps
        return next_t
    
    def _get_t_n(self, timestep: int):
        t_n = timestep * self.t / self.num_inference_steps
        return t_n
    
    def _get_alpha_t(self, timestep: int):
        current_n = timestep
        next_n = self._get_next_timestep(timestep)

        current_t = self._get_t_n(current_n)
        next_t = self._get_t_n(next_n)
        alpha_current = self.alphas_cumprod[current_n]
        alpha_next = self.alphas_cumprod[next_n]

        # formula number 48
        log_alpha_t = np.log(alpha_current) - ((np.log(alpha_next) - np.log(alpha_current)) / (next_t - current_t)) * (self.t - current_t)

        exp_alpha_t = np.exp(log_alpha_t)
        return exp_alpha_t
    
    def _get_sigma_t (self, alpha_t):
        sigma_t = (1 - alpha_t ** 2) ** 0.5
        return sigma_t
    
    def _get_lambda_t (self, alpha_t, sigma_t):
        lambda_t = np.log(alpha_t) - np.log(sigma_t)
        return lambda_t
    
    def _get_exp_h (self, lambda_t, lambda_t_m_1):
        h = lambda_t - lambda_t_m_1
        exp_h = np.exp(h)
        return exp_h
    
    def step(self, timestep: int, latents: torch.Tensor, model_output: torch.Tensor):
        timestep = self._get_previous_timestep(timestep)
        alpha_t_current = self._get_alpha_t(timestep)
        alpha_t_prev = self._get_alpha_t(self._get_previous_timestep(timestep))
        sigma_t_current = self._get_sigma_t(alpha_t_current)
        sigma_t_prev = self._get_sigma_t(self._get_previous_timestep(timestep))
        lambda_t_current = self._get_lambda_t(alpha_t_current, sigma_t_current)
        lambda_t_prev = self._get_lambda_t(alpha_t_prev, sigma_t_prev)
        exp_h = self._get_exp_h(lambda_t_current, lambda_t_prev)
        device = model_output.device
        noise = torch.randn(model_output.shape, generator=self.generator, device=device, dtype=model_output.dtype)

        # formula number 17
        latents_output = (alpha_t_current / alpha_t_prev) * latents - 2 * sigma_t_current * ((exp_h - 1) ** 0.5) * model_output + 2 * sigma_t_current * ((exp_h ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5) * noise
        return latents_output
```